# Laravel Socialite google+ api authorized domain issue?

Tags: laravel, google-api, laravel-socialite

I wan't to use http://127.0.0.1:8000/ as my Authorized Domain in my google+ api for the laravel socailte for testing purpose.i don't have domain to put my code on live still.what shall i do?

Comment: might help https://laraveldaily.com/from-google-api-to-google-sign-in-with-laravel-socialite/

Comment: Google Plus [doesn't exist](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/) any more.

Comment: thanks for the answer @AhmedAboud.wanna know whether i can run google sign in on my local machine( http://127.0.0.1:8000/) but google says it must be a top private domain.any alternatives??